# ParserElement.enablePackrat() doesn't make infixNotation faster

Tags: pyparsing

I use pyparsing (2.1.5) on Python 3.5.0.
I want to make infixNotation faster. I found other people used ParserElement.enablePackrat() for improving infixNotation performance. But I can't make it. My code is follows.

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.enablePackrat()
UNICODE_CHARS = u''.join(
    chr(c) for c in range(65538) if not chr(c).isspace() and
    chr(c) not in '()"'
)
_and_ = Keyword('AND')
_or_ = Keyword('OR')
_not_ = Keyword('NOT')
search_term = ~_and_ + ~_or_ + ~_not_ + Word(UNICODE_CHARS) | QuotedString(
    '"', endQuoteChar='"', unquoteResults=False
)
search_expr = infixNotation(
    search_term,
    [
        (_not_, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
        (Optional(_and_), 2, opAssoc.LEFT), 
        (_or_, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ]
)
parsed_query = search_expr.parseString(user_string)[0].asList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of `infixNotation` only has 3 levels of operators, so packratting won't do much for you. The improvements are usually with 5 or more levels of operators, such as with arithmetic operations.

If you are really trying to crank performance out of `infixNotation`, write your own stripped-down version:

```
"""
BNF

operand = ~and ~or ~not (A-Za-z0-9)... | quoted_string

atom = 'not'? (operand | '(' expr ')')
and_term = atom 'and' atom
or_term = and_term 'or' and_term
"""


_and_ = CaselessKeyword('AND')
_or_ = CaselessKeyword('OR')
_not_ = CaselessKeyword('NOT')
keyword = (_and_ | _or_ | _not_)
search_term = ~keyword + Word(UNICODE_CHARS) | QuotedString('"', endQuoteChar='"', unquoteResults=False)

# use this instead of infixNotation - this is essentially what infixNotation will
# generate, but with fewer FollowedBy's (used to collapse degenerate levels)
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
expr = Forward()
atom_ = search_term | Group(LPAR + expr + RPAR)
atom = Group(_not_ + atom_) | atom_
and_term = Group(atom + ZeroOrMore(_and_ + atom))
or_term = Group(and_term + ZeroOrMore(_or_ + and_term))
expr <<= or_term

# some simple test cases
tests = """
    p and not q
    p and not q or r
    p and not (q or r)
"""

print("compare with using infixNotation")
expr.runTests(tests)

print("compare with using infixNotation")
search_expr = infixNotation(
    search_term,
    [
        (_not_, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
        (Optional(_and_), 2, opAssoc.LEFT), 
        (_or_, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ]
)

search_expr.runTests(tests)
```

The hard-coded version will give output like:

```
p and not q
[[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]]]
[0]:
  [['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]]
  [0]:
    ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]
    [0]:
      p
    [1]:
      AND
    [2]:
      ['NOT', 'q']


p and not q or r
[[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']], 'OR', ['r']]]
[0]:
  [['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']], 'OR', ['r']]
  [0]:
    ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]
    [0]:
      p
    [1]:
      AND
    [2]:
      ['NOT', 'q']
  [1]:
    OR
  [2]:
    ['r']


p and not (q or r)
[[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', [[['q'], 'OR', ['r']]]]]]]
[0]:
  [['p', 'AND', ['NOT', [[['q'], 'OR', ['r']]]]]]
  [0]:
    ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', [[['q'], 'OR', ['r']]]]]
    [0]:
      p
    [1]:
      AND
    [2]:
      ['NOT', [[['q'], 'OR', ['r']]]]
      [0]:
        NOT
      [1]:
        [[['q'], 'OR', ['r']]]
        [0]:
          [['q'], 'OR', ['r']]
          [0]:
            ['q']
          [1]:
            OR
          [2]:
            ['r']
```

Using infixNotation will give:

```
p and not q
[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]]
[0]:
  ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]
  [0]:
    p
  [1]:
    AND
  [2]:
    ['NOT', 'q']


p and not q or r
[[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']], 'OR', 'r']]
[0]:
  [['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']], 'OR', 'r']
  [0]:
    ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', 'q']]
    [0]:
      p
    [1]:
      AND
    [2]:
      ['NOT', 'q']
  [1]:
    OR
  [2]:
    r


p and not (q or r)
[['p', 'AND', ['NOT', ['q', 'OR', 'r']]]]
[0]:
  ['p', 'AND', ['NOT', ['q', 'OR', 'r']]]
  [0]:
    p
  [1]:
    AND
  [2]:
    ['NOT', ['q', 'OR', 'r']]
    [0]:
      NOT
    [1]:
      ['q', 'OR', 'r']
```

The FollowedBy terms that infixNotation adds collapse degenerate levels by ensuring that there are 2 or more terms to be grouped before actually grouping.  They also prevent the calling parse actions for atoms at every level of the operations precedence definition.

If these don't matter to you, then try the stripped-down version.

(Also, please do a little timing on your definition of UNICODE_CHARS - this string will be a little time-consuming to generate. You may want to pre-generate this string to a separate module and just import it.)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I could make it faster 3/4.But I need to make it faster 1/10. I will try psyco or something..

Comment: I move grammer definitions to out of func scope. The performance is improved enoght. It's 1/20. Thanks!

Comment: @OsamuTakayasu, do you mean by "I moved grammar definitions to out of func scope" that your parser and parse code were inside of a function, and that you were building a new parser every time the function was called? Does this include the creation of the UNICODE_CHARS string? As I mentioned in my answer above, when I have done similar building of such a character set, it takes significant time. This is one reason why I have not included this in pyparsing, as it would slow down the import of the module.

Comment: `that your parser and parse code were inside of a function, and that you were building a new parser every time the function was called?` yes..  `Does this include the creation of the UNICODE_CHARS string?` No, it was in global scope. I considered parsing was slow, building a new parser beyond imagination.